# Volcanoes and Lightning

Tags: volcanology, lightning

Just wondering about this question has been popped into my head many times and as what I have seen in some volcanic activities that when a volcano erupts there's a lightning, & i don't know if there's really a storm but I do think volcanoes do attracted to lightning or it produces it's own?

Do volcanoes attracts to lightning?

Comment: Volcanoes like mountains tend to be high ground which means you should expect them to attract lighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volcanic lightning was documented by one of the earliest American volcanologists, [Frank A. Perret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_A._Perret) in the 1940s. However, there was not much, if any, study of the phenomena until recently. According to [this article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2015GL067445/full), the electric charge develops close to the ground where the plume gas thrust region at a few hundred meters above the crater rim, where the overpressure of the turbulent volcanic jets determines the electrification of particles generating a complex charge structure in the growing plume."

[The abstract of another journal article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/2016GL068076/full) indicates that additional lightning can be generated in the stratosphere, "Observations and volcanic plume modeling further suggest that electrical activity was enhanced both by ice formation in the ash clouds >10 km above sea level and development of a low-level charge layer from ground-hugging currents."

Answer (score -1):

Erupting volcanoes release ash. When ash particles collide, it can build a static charge. When that charge is released, there is lightning.

Comment: A dirty thunderstorm?

Comment: When a volcano erupts it releases ash and also a charges which creates lightning?